# Android Emulator not launching on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to start an emulator via AndroidStudio. I followed this installation instructions:

https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x

But whenever I click on the "launch"-icon next to the emulator in the AVDManager no emulator starts. But "launching AVD" is shown when I watch the background-tasks on Android Studio. Also, when launching the emulator from Terminal it times out. What could I do to see what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

> I have faced the same in my Mac , just restart your Mac and try again,
>   and if not working delete the virtual device and create it again

Comment: I already tried that. I also reinstalled the complete android-sdk & Android-Studio, both did not work for me :(

Comment: I cannot see any, that's why I asked if anyone knew where I could possibly see some.